# A factorization of $x^7+x^3+x-1=0$ over rationals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, galois-theory, factoring

I want to solve

$$x^7+x^3+x-1=0.$$

I tried all possible factorization ways (over rational coefficients), e.g.

$$x^7+x^3+x-1=(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)(x^4+rx^3+sx^2+tx+u)$$

But, all possible cases didn't work. Could this equation be related to Galois Theory? Because the equation could not be factored.

Comment: Did you also try quadratic times quintic, linear times sextic?  Are you trying to factor over rationals?

Comment: Descartes' rule of signs shows that it has one real root (which is positive).

Comment: @Doug I tried all possible cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its Galois group is $S_7$, you can compute it in magma

```
P< x >:=PolynomialAlgebra(Rationals());
f:=x^7+x^3+x-1;
G:=GaloisGroup(f);
print G;
```

It implies that must be irreducible, so you cannot factorice it in rationals.

Comment: Edited, it was a typo

Comment: Is the Galois group a solvable group?

Comment: No $S_7$ is not a solvable group.

Comment: No, since for $n>4$ $A_n$ is simple